# IIS7 integrated pipeline mode slower than classic

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, iis-7, integrated-pipeline-mode

We are running a complex 64-bit ASP.NET 2.0 application on W2008 R2 Standard and stress tests done with VS2008 Team System have indicated that integrated pipeline mode is 30% slower than classic mode.

We have compared the application traces extensively and it appears that integrated mode is uniformly slower than classic. That is, there is no single point that causes delays in integrated mode.

This is quite the opposite to everything Microsoft says about the integrated pipeline, so it might be that there is something quite wrong with the configuration of the integrated mode or the server. But we have not found any settings that would have any effect on this. Some complaints that Sharepoint and reporting services are slower in integrated mode can be found, but our application does not use them so this is quite likely unrelated.

Any ideas what might cause the poor performance or how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at enabling tracing and see where your performance is slower. there is a good article here:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/9827.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no single place where the performance is slower - each phase in trace is about the same amount slower (in %) with integrated pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at thread usage in perfmon?

I have not tested this myself, but I am guessing that Integrated Pipeline will use more ASP.NET worker threads since all requests pass thru the managed handler.

You may find more details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650682.aspx

See my question here:

[IIS7 Integrated vs Classic Pipeline - which uses more ASP.NET threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337773/iis7-integrated-vs-classic-pipeline-which-uses-more-asp-net-threads)